# New Column of Table not Selecting

Tags: sql-server

I have added a new column in table, when I select this table with schema name, new column shows, when i select this column without mention of schema name, SQL does not identify new column, so basically:

`Select new_column From schema.table` works 
`Select new_column from table` does not work

Please tell me why this is happening & how to correct this, i want this column available without mentioning schema name.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Management Studio? Maybe it is stupid, but using this tool, you must refresh environment to see newly created column or table.

Comment: Yes, also an application sending insert query without schema name is failing due to newly added column

Comment: Are you sure, you are not using transaction or commiting it? Which database version it is?

Comment: I am not using any transactions, database version is 100

Answer (score 2):

If you are not getting new column when you are selecting from table whithout schema name, then this means that that schema name is not default and you have 2 tables with that name both in default and mensioned schema. You can have tables with same name in different schemas.

Comment: how would i make this column available without having to mention schema name ?

Comment: You shoud change default schema for user which contains that table: `ALTER USER Mary51 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Purchasing;`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, is your intent to have 2 different tables with the same name, but in different schema?  If so, you should schema-qualify all object names to avoid ambiguity, including objects in the `dbo` schema.

Comment: @DanGuzman, you can omit schema name and default schema for user will be used

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, I understand it is not a requirement to specify the schema name.  I am saying it is a best practice to specify it, not only to avoid ambiguity, but to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that column is not getting selected because I am querying a view, not a table, and I need to add this column to view as well.

Confusion occurred because in previous versions of product(Dynamics AX) they(Microsoft) did not apply schema to database objects, now they added schema & created a view for backward compatibility.